# What's the difference between a hash table and a dictionary in C

Tags: c

I know the differences between hash table and dictionary when it comes to C#.

- The hashtable type optimizes lookups. It computes a hash of each key you add. It then uses this hash code to look up the element very quickly.
- The Dictionary type provides fast lookups with keys to get values. With it we use keys and values of any type, including ints and strings.

Dictionary objects offer type safety in C# whereas hash tables don't.

I would like to know if there are similar differences when it comes to C language?

Comment: There are no standard hash tables or dictionary at the level of the C standard.  Consequently, there's no meaningful way to make a statement about the 'difference between hash table and dictionary' until you specify which implementations you are considering.

Comment: you mean to say a dictionary is derived from hastable in C or does Dictinary has its own implementation in C ?

Comment: I mean there is no standard implementation of anything called hash table in C.  Likewise, there is no standard implementation of anything called dictionary in C.  You are seeking to compare two non-existent data types — which is kind of tricky.  That isn't to say there aren't implementations of either or both types in C (see [POSIX hash tables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hcreate.html), for instance); but because they aren't standard, you'll have to specify which ones you want to compare.

Comment: The most instructive thing you could would be to write a set of hash table and dictionary functions in C.  Once you've got them working correctly, you will understand the differences (or lack thereof) completely.

Comment: @krrishna The text of the question is about C#, but it's tagged C. Could you clarify?

Comment: @TimothyJones: I think that the question is stating the case of how the two types differ in C#, and then asking what happens with the equivalent types in C, on the assumption that the types do in fact exist (which my comments state do not exist in 'the Standard', meaning ISO/IEC 9899:2011).

Comment: Ah, I think your interpretation is correct. If you make your comments an answer, I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know the differences between hashtable and dictionary when it comes to c#.

I'm going to convince you that you don't understand Hash Table and Dictionary even in C#.

Dictionary is an [Abstract Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). A Dictionary can refers to any data structures that provides a key to value mapping.

A Hash Table, on the other hand, is a Concrete Data Structure. A Hash Table uses a hashing function to convert keys to indices of an internal array and has a collision resolution.

A Hash Table is a kind of Dictionary because a Hash Table provides a key to value mapping. However, not all Dictionary are Hash Tables; there are infinitely many ways to create a data type that provides a key to value mapping, such as with Binary Search Tree or as a sorted array with keys in even indices and values in odd indices.

In other words, when you're talking about Dictionary you're specifying an interface (what the data type should look like from the outside), while when talking about HashTable you're specifying an implementation (how the data should actually be stored).

C# confuses this slightly by specifying a specific concrete data structure for its Dictionary class in its documentation, but this shouldn't detract you from understanding the distinction between the two concepts. C has neither dictionary nor hashtable implementation in its standard library, but the distinction between a Dictionary and Hash Table is language-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks @Lie Ryan . You clarified my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Hash Table in C
The idea of hashing is to distribute the entries (key/value pairs) across an array of buckets.

```
index = f(key, array_size)
```

Dictionary in C
The C Programming Language presents a simple dictionary (hash table) data structure.

So the only difference is that it shows hash table uses key/value pair but dictionary uses its data structure.